# Cordova-plugin-googlemaps blank screen on Play store

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-keystore

My Ionic app is using the **cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.3.9** plugin, and everything had been working on iOS and Android until yesterday.

**Cordova android**: 5.1.1

**Cordova iOS**: 4.1.1

**Cordova CLI**: 6.2.0

**Ionic Framework Version**: 1.2.1-nightly-1867

**Ionic CLI Version**: 2.0.0

Yesterday, I pushed a new version on the stores and now I’ve got a blank screen instead of the Google map. The map works on debug mode on my Android phone but not in production mode, I mean from the Play store.

Further to several researches, I have deduced that the problem came from Google Maps Android API v2 key. Thus, I have generated a new key and reinstalled the cordova plugin with the same command but with the new key :

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="MY_NEW_API_KEY" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="myIosKey"
```

After that, the map was not working even on debug mode… Therefore, I added the fingerprint of the `debug.keystore` in the Google Developer console. After this the map started to work again on debug mode

I did the same operation for the production version, using the fingerprint of the **release keystore**, used to build the production APK.

Despite this, I still have a blank screen instead of the map, when I download the app from the Play store.

Comment: Please note that [rushing volunteers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) does not go down well here - your urgencies are not anyone else's urgencies, since they usually have plenty of their own.

Comment: I am sorry if this sounded rude, I am french and and I am note familiar with this rules.

Comment: I imagine that being demanding of French volunteers in the French language is not regarded as polite either, but thanks! Not a rule that is specific to here, no - just good practice whenever one is asking for help from strangers, anywhere on the internet `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

To build my production APK I use **Ionic CLI**.

I don't know why but the command did not add the cordova-plugin-googlemaps plugin to the signed APK.
To solve that, I installed the plugin with the **--save** option :

cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="MY_ANDROID_KEY" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="MY_IOS_KEY" --save